# Is possible to split an nautilus window in horizontal?

Tags: gnome, nautilus, window, split

The window splits vertically when we press the `F3` key, it's possible to split the window horizontally?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, this is not possible, and in 13.04 the split window feature has been removed entirely, in favour of Tabs and side-by-side windows.  Here's [the commit that removed them](https://git.gnome.org/browse/nautilus/commit/src/nautilus-window-pane.c?id=b8d5b4a7bcf47ed34a6343c95bcc3b079255c0a0).

Others [have suggested similar functionality](http://brainstorm.ubuntu.com/idea/2589/), but since this feature has been retired from Nautilus, you might be looking for alternate file managers.

Answer (score 0):

Try Nemo, which is a fork of Nautilus. You can find good instructions here: http://www.noobslab.com/2013/05/install-nemo-file-manager-in-ubuntu.html